# laravel5.1 edit sendResetLink() function

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, reset

How did I need to edit this code:

```
$response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('username'),     function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        $message->from('hello@app.com', 'Your ApplicationZ');
    });
```

So I can use this e-mail template:

```
Hey {{ $username }}
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('reset/'.$token) }}
```

The difference to the default function is to use the username to say a nice hello to the user. I don't want to rewrite the whole password "reset" method.

Comment: closed. laravel sends the user object to the email too. simple `{{ $user->username }}` will work.

Comment: Please add it as answer to make it clear this problem has been already solved

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sends the user object to the email too. So, simple `{{ $user->username }}` will work.